# How to assign property values from method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, properties, variable-assignment, send

I have the method :

```
def mov destination_register, source
  if source == :ax then send("#{destination_register}=", @ax) end
end
```

where **destination_register** is a symbol(:ax, :bxm :cx, :dx). I also have properties : @ax, @bx, @cx, @dx. if source is always a symbol among :ax, :bx, :cx, :dx how could I assign the value of destination_register property with the value of source ? I tried with send but I still don't know if it will work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Exactly. The method is part of a module that is included in a class that has that @ax

Comment: I am confused. In your question, you are saying that `source` is the name of a register, e.g. `:ax` which means that `mov` would be used like `mov(:ax, :bx)`, but in this comment you are saying that `mov` should be used with a value, like `mov(:ax, 2)`?

Comment: I'm confused by your reply as well, but am assuming that your question is correct (i.e. that `source` is the symbol for a register). I'm going to delete my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you want to do, but something like this might work:

```
def mov(destination_register, source)
  send(:"#{destination_register}=", instance_variable_get(:"@{source}"))
end
```

However, if you have a getter method for your instance variable, it would be much better to use that instead of getting the instance variable directly:

```
def mov(destination_register, source)
  send(:"#{destination_register}=", send(:"{source}"))
end
```

And if you want to violate encapsulation *anyway*, then why not go the whole nine yards:

```
def mov(destination_register, source)
  instance_variable_set(:"#@{destination_register}", instance_variable_get(:"@{source}"))
end
```

Comment: I guess that this will work. I just wanted to ask also: how can I call the mov method from the object with two arguments passed to it? IS there such a version of the 'send' that takes method name and two arguments or I just have to expect this '*args' instead two position arguments?

Comment: `send` takes the method name and however many arguments you want to pass. It simply passes all arguments except the first one to the method named by the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
def mov destination_register, source
  instance_variable_set(:"#{destination_register}", instance_variable_get(:"@{source}")
end
```